# Looking for a specified word in a database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a database called `LogInData` where I have information about user names, password, email address stored in a table called `LOGIN`. When you register you can't use an already existing username because I am using this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mike\Documents\LogInData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From LOGIN where Username = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and Email = '" + textBox3.Text + "'", con);

con.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username already existing.");
}
```

And my question is: how does this code exactly work? I know that the first line creates a connection to the database. But what about the second row  with the `SqlDataAdapter` and the row with the if?

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Select Count(*) From [LOGIN] ...

Comment: What word are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **do not use that code in production**, where any malicious user can read, write or delete in your database. Use SQL parameters, not string building with +.

As for the code, you connect to a database then you create an SqlDataAdapter that fills a DataTable from the query you gave it, which counts the number of users with that username and email.